# How to hide/disable the "More Options" link when displaying the vCalendar in Gmail

Tags: google-calendar-api, vcalendar, ical.net

Using Ical.Net library, a vcalendar similar below is generated:

```
    BEGIN:VCALENDAR
    METHOD:REQUEST
    PRODID:-//github.com/rianjs/ical.net//NONSGML ical.net 4.0//EN
    VERSION:2.0
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    ATTENDEE;CN=test@gmail.com.com;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;RS
    VP=TRUE:mailto:test@gmail.com
    DESCRIPTION:This is the description text
    DTSTAMP:20200604T075151Z
    DTSTART:20200604T165500Z
    LOCATION:
    ORGANIZER;CN=PHN:mailto:organizer@gmail.com
    SEQUENCE:0
    STATUS:CONFIRMED
    SUMMARY:Testing
    TRANSP:OPAQUE
    UID:LJf40Nfh2mZ+Ta1JFhlYRZDh2By3qeY6UMA6vcy525M=
    END:VEVENT
    END:VCALENDAR
```

In one email recipient, it shows up as:
[Add To Calendar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCyWK.png)

However on another email recipient, it shows up as:

[Has More Options link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpQWa.png)

First,how can i make the two email show consistent rendering.  Second, how can i remove the "More Options" link?

Comment: I don't think this can be edited. Why would you tho? It gives the user invited an option to add notes to the event.

Comment: I don't want user to edit it but i want the  event show up automatically to the user's calendar.  If I change the method to PUBLISH and just remove the ATTENDEES, it does not automatically add the event to the calendar.